# How to draw NSString atPoint withAttributes and adjust SIZE?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uifont

I am able to draw my NSStrings, but I have not been able to adjust the size when I draw them. My drawRect: method is:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{

NSArray *objectArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:80.0f], nil];
NSArray *keyArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"NSFontAttributeName", nil];
NSMutableDictionary *textAttributes = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:objectArray forKeys:keyArray];
NSString *myTestString = @"Test String";
[textAttributes setObject:[UIColor redColor] forKey:NSForegroundColorAttributeName];
[myTestString drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(20, 30) withAttributes:textAttributes];
[myTestString drawInRect:CGRectMake(50, 50, 500, 500) withAttributes:textAttributes];

NSLog(@"wrote %@ with %@", myTestString, textAttributes);
}
```

The textAttributes look good, and the font information is returned as:

```
 NSFontAttributeName = "<UICTFont: 0x14eeff40> font-family: \".HelveticaNeueInterface-M3\"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 80.00pt"
```

I can change the color correctly with the attributes array, why does this result in text that is the default 10pt Size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSAttributedString is what you want. The UICatalog sample code has an example of NSAttributedString usage:

```
#pragma mark - UIPickerViewDataSource

- (NSAttributedString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView attributedTitleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    NSMutableAttributedString *attrTitle = nil;

    // note: for the custom picker we use custom views instead of titles
    if (pickerView == self.myPickerView)
    {
        if (row == 0)
        {
            NSString *title;
            if (component == 0)
                title = [self.pickerViewArray objectAtIndex:row];
            else
                title = [[NSNumber numberWithInt:row] stringValue];

            // apply red text for normal state
            attrTitle = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:title];
            [attrTitle addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName
                          value:[UIColor redColor]
                          range:NSMakeRange(0, [attrTitle length])];
        }
    }

    return attrTitle;
}
```

The Stanford U MOOC course on iOS (run by Paul Hegarty and [available on iTunes](https://itunes.apple.com/us/course/developing-ios-7-apps-for/id733644550)) gives an overview of NSAttributedString use in lecture 4. Lecture 5 also features an NSAttributedString code demo that you can follow.  Finally, github user m2mtech has published [repositories of all code exercises and assignments for the course](https://github.com/m2mtech?tab=repositories), you can download the relevant project files [here](https://github.com/m2mtech/attributor).

Comment: You can also use NSMutableAttributedString.

Comment: If you can only adjust a minimum set of attributes then I guess I don't understand why you are forced to use drawAtPoit: withAttributes.